# PrimeVue DataTable

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, primevue

If I add the `:lazy="true"` to the as shown below:

```
<DataTable
   :value="cars"
   :lazy="true"
   :filters="filters"
   :paginator="true"
   :rows="10"
   :totalRecords="totalRecords"
   sortMode="multiple"
   :loading="loading"
   @page="onPage($event)"
>
```

The column filter and sort doesn't work

Example code: https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/#/datatable/filter

How can I make filter and sort work with :lazy as true?

Jobby

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure one rule for each column with data, for example a table of studens ( id , name), and add the json field property name of the associated column in `:globalFilterFields`.

```
<Datatable :filters="filters" :globalFilterFields="[ 'id', 'name' ]">
  <Column field="id" header="ID"/>
  <Column field="name" header="Name"/>
</Datatable>

...

const filters = ref({
  global: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS},
  id: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.EQUALS},
  name: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS},
});
```

This way you are telling DataTable to filter the column Id and Name, using the defined rules, just remember to use the correct mactchMode to filter numbers, dates or strings, `FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS` is used with strings.

Answer (score 0):

As I was trying out lazy load (server side) and global filtering, I come to realise the :filters event emitter is not working.

After a wander in the their typescript file, I come across a command as in the snippet

```
    /**
     * Event to emit after filtering, not triggered in lazy mode.
     * @param {DataTableFilterEvent} event - Custom filter event.
     */
    filter(event: DataTableFilterEvent): void;
```

So I think if you trying to listen to the global filters change event there's no chance, though you can use v-model to two-way bind the search string.

The example at their [doc](https://primevue.org/datatable/#lazy_load) looks like the individual column filter works.